# Spring Camel Email Configuration Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-camel

I am trying to send email from my spring mvc based web application using apache camel. But my tomcat is not getting up because of some wrong configuration i guess.

Can you please help me?

```
**camel-config.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
                                http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

            <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
               <contextScan>com.aaa.bbb.ccc.service</contextScan>
            </camelContext>
        </beans>


@Service
public class NotificationService 
{
    @Produce(uri = "smtp://mysmtp.company.com")
    private ProducerTemplate template;

    public void send(String from,String to,String cc,String bcc,String subject,String body) 
    {
         template.sendBodyAndHeaders(body,Requirement_Specific_Code);
    }
}

Spring Jar: version 3.1.0
Camel: camel-core-2.10.3.jar 
       camel-mail-2.10.3.jar 
       camel-mina-2.10.3.jar 
       camel-spring-2.10.3.jar

**:Issue:** Once i run tomcat i am having below error.

 2013-05-21 19:08:05,581 ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [camel-config.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 2 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/camel-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 225; TargetNamespace.1: Expecting namespace 'http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring', but the target namespace of the schema document is 'http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
```

I am not getting where am i wrong.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Are you sure  that the camel jars you've listed are the only ones you have in your classpath? It seems that Spring is tring to validate you xml with an old version of the XSD that may be present in another jar.

Comment: Yes, there are only those camel jar in WEB-INF/lib. Total jar are 55 including camel jars. I should not ask but if i post list of those 55 jar, would it be possible to suggest any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `camel-contex.xml` looks like you posted it? The error says:

```
Expecting namespace 'http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring', but the target namespace of the schema document is 'http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring'
```

So somewhere you are using the wrong XML namespace `http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring`. Where?

Comment: Yes, I have verified in all the xml file i have. I haven't used any where 'http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring'

Comment: Your guess was right. Actually there was a little confict with my ant target which was actually not reflecting the changes. Now i have corrected that camel-confix.xml and the error is as:
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: I found resolution for NoSuchMethod and that was mismatch of jar and now it's resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There was many issues which i found one by one and resolved in that sequence too. However for others help, i am concluding in bried.

Issue/Solution:
1) There was some conflict in Ant target which was not deploying the camel-config.xml. Provide xml in the question is little in correct. The correct is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
                        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.10.3.xsd">
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
       <contextScan/>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

2) I revised(Added/Updated/Removed) jar and those are as follows.

- camel-core-2.11.0
- camel-mail-2.11.0
- camel-mina-2.11.0
- camel-spring-2.11.0
- mina-core-1.1.7
- mail-1.4.5
- mina-core-2.0.0-M3
- slf4j-api-1.7.5
- slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5

If your jar is not as per above you are likely to get errors as follows.

- org.apache.mina.core.buffer.IOBuffer class not available (mina-core-2.0.0-M3)
- ByteArray class not available.
- Can not auto create smtp.

Thanks everyone for supporting and hope this information will be helpful to some one in future.